# C++ String Array to Text Document

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to create a program that will make an array of data entered until a stop commands is entered and have it log it into a text document. I am getting a crash of Microsoft Visual Studio after i enter the Fist name and Last name fields.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string stream;
    int outputString;
    string dataOutput;
    string dataArray[1];
    bool askData = true;
    int i = 0;

    ofstream outfile("data.txt");

    while (askData) {
        cout << "Type First then Last Name or \"$Stop\" to save and exit" <<     "\n" << "First: ";

        getline(cin, firstName);
        if (firstName == "$Stop") {
            askData = false;

        }
        else {
            cout << "Last: ";
            cin >> lastName;
            cout << "\n\n\n";
            dataOutput = firstName + " " + lastName + "; ";
            dataArray [1 + i] = dataOutput;
            i++;
        }


        cout << dataOutput;

    }

    outfile << dataArray;
    outfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: 
Also tried.

```
string dataArray[];
```

then later assigning it to an incrementing variable.

```
int i = 0;

dataArray[i];
i++;
```

Can you tell me why this doesnt work?

Comment: `string dataArray[1];` is an array of a single string. It can only store one value, not `1 + i` values.

Comment: You probably wanted to use `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

Comment: Look into [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You can add elements to it with automatic resizing using `data_vec.push_back(elem);`.

Comment: `dataArray [1 + i]` is wrong, regardless. The first element of `dataArray` is `dataArray [0]`. `outfile << dataArray;` doesn't do what you think it does either.

Comment: How do I outfile the array, i used `dataArray.push_back(dataOutput);`
I have `ofstream outfile("data.txt");` but `outfile << dataArray;` gives me an error. i tried `stringstream dataArray` before the outfile but i still get the error.